# Find screen a QWidget is located on

Tags: qt, qt5

With functions

```
QApplication::desktop()->screenCount();
QApplication::desktop()->screenGeometry();
```

I find how much screens exist on my system and on which screen coordinates they are located. Now I want to find out on which screen a QWidget is located at. How can I do that? Do I have to check the coordinates of the QWidget against the screen-coordinates or is there a more elegant way for this which returns the screen-number directly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the function you should be looking for is this

```
int QDesktopWidget::screenNumber(const QPoint &point) const
```

This is an overloaded function.
Returns the index of the screen that contains the point, or the screen which is the shortest distance from the point.

since i don't have multiple screens, you can check for yourself, the QWidget::pos() function provides the QPoint

Edit:
As suggested by scopchanov in comments, you can also use

```
QDesktopWidget::screenNumber(const QWidget *widget = Q_NULLPTR)
```

Answer (score 18):

`QDesktopWidget` is deprecated in newer Qt versions ([5.11 and above](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.11/qdesktopwidget.html), [not deprecated in 5.10](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.10/qdesktopwidget.html)).

Since Qt 5.10 there is `QGuiApplication::screenAt(QPoint)` as a replacement for `screenNumber(QPoint)`.

Seems there is no direct replacement for `screenNumber(QWidget*)`. However, it is [possible](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-68785) to get information about the screen where the widget in question is located through `QScreen` pointer:

```
QScreen *screen = widget->window()->windowHandle()->screen();
qDebug() << screen->geometry()
                << screen->availableGeometry();
```

Comment: somehow that doesn't work for me (Windows, Qt5.13).

Comment: Why on earth is `screenNumber` deprecation documentation on Qt docs not LINKING to screenAt? This would have saved me quite some time. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

In addition to Sillicomancers answer, I use the following code to replace the depricated `QDesktopWidget::availableGeometry(const QWidget *widget)`

```
QScreen* pScreen = QGuiApplication::screenAt(widget->mapToGlobal({widget->width()/2,0}));
QRect availableScreenSize = pScreen->availableGeometry();
```

which uses the screen where the middle of the top of `widget` is located.

Answer (score 5):

[QWidget::screen()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#screen) introduced in Qt5.14.